# Usage of *variable in scanf and why we use it?

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

hello i'm a beginner and i keep seeing this in codes but i cant figure what exactly it means...
like the example below

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c1;
    do
    {
        scanf_s("%c%*c", &c1, 1);
        if ((c1>='a' && c1<='z')||(c1 >= 'A' && c1 <= 'Z'))
        {
            printf("%c  %d", c1, c1);
        }

    } while (c1!=0);
    return 0;
}
```

like here does it convert char or store its value??
(%*c) in scanf is a mystery to me ass far as i undestood it's kinda a reference to memory but doesn't initiate any variable it just point to what value is stored in the memory ...
Am i right???

Comment: Out of interest, where does this example come from?

Comment: You don't have a `*variable` anywhere. Do you mean the `*` in the `scanf` format string? A [`scanf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) might be helpful for that.

Comment: Note that the example you show would break down on systems that doesn't use ASCII encoding for characters. If you want to know if a character is a letter use [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha).

Comment: it just an example c1 is defined as a character and in scanf it read %c and %*c later it prints ascii code and character i just want to know what did *c did here

Comment: _"An asterisk (*) following the percent sign suppresses assignment of the next input field, which is interpreted as a field of the specified type. The field is scanned but not stored."_ In your format specification `"%c%*c"` it means to read one character and ignore the next one.

Comment: As a beginner I'd avoid complicated `scanf` usage. Concerntrate on other stuff for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the C Standard (7.21.6.2 The fscanf function)

> 3....After the %, the following appear in sequence:
>
> — **An optional assignment-suppressing character ***.
>
> — An optional decimal integer greater than zero that specifies the
>   maximum field width (in characters).
>
> — An optional length modifier that specifies the size of the receiving
>   object.
>
> — A conversion specifier character that specifies the type of
>   conversion to be applied.

and (K.3.5.3.2 The fscanf_s function)

> 4 The fscanf_s function is equivalent to fscanf except that the c, s,
>   and [ conversion specifiers apply to a pair of arguments (**unless
>   assignment suppression is indicated by a
>   ***)....

So in this call

```
scanf_s("%c%*c", &c1, 1);
```

the format `%*c` suppresses assigning of the read character to an argument. Usually such an approach is used to read from the buffer the new line character that appears after the user presses the key Enter.